# System.MissingMethodException: Method not found

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Пытаюсь запустить его на Apphabor c SQL Server.

Получаю следующую ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То, что вы рассказываете, очень интересно. А в чём вопрос-то?

Comment: Вопрос в том ,что хочу узнать как устранить  мою ошибку.

Comment: Влад, подскажите, что следует добавить в мой вопрос, чтобы получить адекватные ответы.

Comment: Окей, смотрите. Во-первых, кроме скриншота, неплохо бы включить текст Message в Exception'е, а также stack trace. Это раз. Затем, было бы очень неплохо рассказать, как можно за минимальное число шагов воспроизвести проблему. Это сложнее, конечно. При этом, возможно, имеет смысл написать короткое консольное приложение из пары строчек, которое проблему воспроизводит. И ещё нужны инструкции, как его запустить, чтобы воспроизвести проблему. Это позволит нам получить ту же проблему на своих компьютерах, в таком виде анализировать её намного легче.

Comment: С другой стороны, для вашей проблемы, и правда, выглядит так, как будто бы вы забыли подключить нужную версию нужной библиотеки.

Comment: Подождите, сейчас уже stack trace и exception text не так важны, так что это на будущее. А вот то, как именно вы подключаете ваши сборки — особенно, какие версии вы подключаете! — очень важно.

Comment: Проблема возникла после этой строки: Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new Devtalk.EF.CodeFirst.DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChanged<ApplicationDbConte‌​xt>()) в методе OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder). Библиотеки подключаю с помощью директивы using или nuget  install.

Comment: using не интересно, а вот команды nuget важны. добавьте их лучше всего в вопрос

Comment: Я команды не вызывал, поиском искал библиотеку и нажимал инсталл,  всё  подключилось в references.

Comment: Можете рассказать, какие особенности взаимодейсрвия библиотеки Devtalk.Ef  с Entity Framework 6?

Comment: Окей, хорошо. Но тогда вам придётся глянуть в ссылки, какие же версии и каких сборок реально подключились.

Comment: По поводу Devtalk.Ef ничего не могу сказать — не знаю, что это такое.

Comment: Влад, а вы имели опыт  хостинга проектов на MVC5  на appharbor.com?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в проекте не подключена сборка System.Data.Entity.dll.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста,  как мне правильно её подключить в мой проект.

Comment: После добавления этой строки : Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new Devtalk.EF.CodeFirst.DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChanged<ApplicationDbContext>());
возникла та ошибка, entity framework  переустановил, не помогло.

Comment: @Greg: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Comment: Подключил reference- system.data.entity, сделал rebuild,  осталась та ошибка.

Comment: Подозреваю, там проблема с версиями просто. @Greg - пропишите правильную версию в config-файле, используя bindingRedirects. Для более удобного управления зависимостями, рекомендовал бы использовать paket, он умеет прописывать правильные редиректы за вас. https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать после установки  Пакета в мой проект.

Comment: Думаю,что проблема не с версиями, т.к.  удалив ту строчку, о которой выше писал, и все заработало.

Comment: Как сделать, чтобы вместе с той строкой работало, непонятно.